# Database for a java application in cluster

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, architecture, cluster-computing

I'd like to play around with `kubernetes`, I'm able to start a simple app, but now I'd like to design something more complex. Nevertheless I can't figure out, how to handle the database access in such architecture.

Let's say I have 100 pod replicas of some simple chat application. They all need to access the same database (or more like data set) and perform `CRUD` operations upon them. How to design it to keep the data consistent and eliminate the risk of deadlocks?

If possible, I'd like to use `SQL`-like database, so I can comfortably use `hibernate` and other tools I'm familiar with.

Is this even possible or do I have to use totally a different approach? What is the name of the technology or architecture I'm searching for?

Comment: Surely this is just analogous to multi-threaded database access and deadlocks / locking strategies - RDBMs vs NoSql etc - a well trodden path - why does kubernetes specifically alter the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'm wondering whether there is a specific design pattern to use. Because it's different, whether you have 2-3 servers or hundreds of servers with servers with micro services, which instantly need to do something with the db. Or isn't it and I can depend that the MySQL/Oracle/whatever database will handle all the problems by itself? Note: I use databases as a software developer, but don't have any deep knowledge about them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use a connection pool to reduce this number and make the connection settings more aggressive/elastic;

2) Split your microservices in such way the access to the persistence is a microservice exposing your CRUD service to your persistence(mysql/rdms/nosql/etc). In that way you most likely don't need hundreds of replicas of your pods.

3) Deadlocks / locking strategies - as Andrew mentioned in the comments, it's more related to your software development architecture rather than K8s itself. There are plenty of ways to deal with that with pros/cons.